In an expandable option of a context menu, should the expandable option be clickable?
I have this context menu on the web platform (Angular Material) where the "Details" option is expandable by hovering. It is clickable, but since users might not know that, there's also a "Details" option in it.
However, I understand that this repetition looks very unusual.
Should I make the expandable "Details" button not clickable? That would make the access to this functionality a little less optimal.
Changing the "Details" sub-option's name to something else also feels weird because it has the exact same functionality as the expandable option.
Any suggestions?


A typical X-Y problem. Get rid of "details" in the submenu somehow as it is ambiguous. You present contact, skills, custom fields, documents and additional modules as being details. What does “details” mean among the other sub-items? See what I mean?

The word 'Details' just by itself is ambiguous. The label should provide clarity by itself as much as possible. Here it begs the question – 'Details about what?' From the way I see it, the parent option is no different from an ellipsis (⋯) icon considering that it gives further options about the topic.
If 'Details' is a necessary option in the sub-menu and it links to another screen/section by the same name, then that's where it should be.
I see that the parent is meant to provide an edit page with the pencil icon beside it. If that is the case, then the label should read 'Edit [topic]'.

There is nothing more obvious than adding a redirect icon


but do you think that the left "Details" button should be clickable?

It depends on the context, if the button leads to the menu options displayed on a page, yes
